# Establish a P2P connection, or "pass the socket" to somebody else

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'd like to understand better what can be done with networks, and I'm currently working on some Android apps where I'd like to implement some kind of P2P connections, over WiFi and/or 3G/4G, somehow.  I know there are many difficulties that arise in doing so, but still, I'd like to know how, or to have a direction on how I could begin to tackle the problem.

I had an idea about it, which I think would avoid me all the hassle of NAT traversing if it works (I definitely not pretend I'm the first guy to come up with this):

[image: Handshake then transfer of socket own]

Jim and John both connect to the server.  The server put them in the same box and relay one another's message.  At some point, the server get bored of wasting his bandwidth.  He has a connected socket to Jim, and a connected socket to John.  So 'somehow' (perhaps magically), he gives his to-John-Socket to Jim, and vice-versa.

Thus the new scenario : Jim comes and say "Hey server, gimme a socket to John":
Server: Ok wait here until he arrives.
John: Hey server, gimme a socket to Jim.
Server: Oh, there you are!  Jim, take John's socket.  John, take Jim's socket.  See ya guys!

Server goes back to his little business while Jim and John do their own things.

I guess it is definitely not this simple.  So how should I do this?  If I need to traverse NAT gateways at some point, how can I do that (myself, without a library) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're attempt is acheivable but certainly difficult and time consuming to do if you're starting from zero. I'm not an expert in network programming but I know enough to appreciate the complications that would be encountered.

If you'd like some background information on network programming then I would recommend the book [Unix Network Programming](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Unix-Network-Programming-Addison-Wesley-Professional/dp/0131411551/) even if you're not familiar with UNIX. Although it's very technical and details C code it gives a very good background into sockets etc, as it is from UNIX that came the idea of sockets.

If I were doing something similar then I'd be tempted to try and look at some open-source projects such as listed [here](http://www.junauza.com/2008/01/freeopen-source-p2p-file-sharing.html) or even the [Yahoo Messenger SDK](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/). Googling 'open source p2p' might give some pointers too though I imagine a lot of it is in C/C++.